# Timestamp is not writing during xml searilization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to write

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(object);
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.ASCII);
xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, obj);
xmlString = ASCIIByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray())
```

after serialized value with time stamp is removed why? and how i can serialized  timestamp format value in c#?

Comment: What type is the timestamp? Is it a `DateTime` or did you mean `TimeSpan`? How does `obj` look like?

Comment: No it is not and timestamp is time format which is provided in db.I am getting time in this format 01:43:12 e.g but when serialize him it is not writing giving empty value.

Comment: We need to know more than that to help you. What is the actual *type* of the timestamp. Is is `string`? Could you show us the code of the class you're serializing and the generated XML?

Comment: Using Assembly System.Xml.dll, v4.0.30319 for serialization in c#

Comment: Huh? That's not what I asked. Could you read what I asked again?

Comment: I got it your question this is .net library which is used and time format already i have mention 02:23:34

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check. First the following line:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(object);
```

This is not valid C# and it will not compile. I think you meant:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
```

Then make sure that Timestamp is a property on this obj that has a public getter and setter for it to be XML serialized.

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
var obj = new Foo
{
    Timestamp = DateTime.Now
};

var xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    xs.Serialize(stream, obj);
    string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Timestamp>2012-03-13T08:21:12.5391233+01:00</Timestamp>
</Foo>
```